# How often Azure calculates the forecast and actual billing?

Tags: azure, azure-billing

As per Microsoft

> Estimated charges for the current billing period are updated six times per day.

but it does say how often it calculates the forecast vs actual billing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cost & usage data is typically available within 8 ~ 24 hours. And the cost analysis is just a tool to visualize the accumulated data, the interval at which the information are updated might be dependent to several factors as described [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/understand-cost-mgt-data#cost-and-usage-data-updates-and-retention)